# How to put 3 inputs and 1 selector in 3 columns grid

Tags: input-fields, grid, lean-ux

I need an outside perspective) The hanging “Mode Tunnel” selector is very annoying. Are there any options for configuring this differently so that it doesn’t hang like that?[image]

Comment: Why is it annoying? What usability issue does it present? To me it looks fine - all the TextInputs are together, the toggle is both visually and functionally separate - seems all good. If it's an aestetic issue, then it's probably all relative, so whatever you think looks better will go. Just make sure you don't introduce usability issues while making it prettier.